# Sorting doubles by column

Tags: linux

I have a file in the format

```
word1\tnumber1
word2\tnumber2
etc
```

where number is a double written like `1,232E-2`

How can I sort it using linux sort command? (I read a post where they used -V, but it doesn't work in my case)

Answer (score 1):

Will this work for you?

```
$ cat input.txt
word1\1,232E-2
word2\1,132E-2
word3\1,332E-2

$ awk -F\\ '{print $2}' input.txt | sort -n
1,132E-2
1,232E-2
1,332E-2
```

or if the data is tab-separated, just use

```
$ awk '{print $2}' f1 | sort -n
```

or third option, to sort the whole lines

```
$ sort -k2 -n input.txt
word2   1,132E-2
word1   1,232E-2
word3   1,332E-2
```

Tweek it to your needs.

Comment: It doesn't sort correctly (I used the tab separated answer)

Comment: (It works when there is no 'E' power for the numbers)

Comment: then please update you question with some proper input and expected output and I'll take a look at it.